# Navigated event doesn't fire up on specific pages using WebView - Xamarin Android C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, events, webview

Could someone explain me why Navigated event in WebView doesn't fire up while searching stuff on https://m.olx.pl? I'm using WebView from Xamarin.

I tried many other events and any of them fire up after i put some phrase in "Search" text box or when I navigate on this site.

Comment: Have you tried other URL to see if it called `Navigated`? In addition, you can follow this issue: [Webview navigation events are inconsistent](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10350).

Answer (score 0):

You can use CustomRenderer and add this:

```
 public class AuthWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        ...
        public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
        {
            base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
            var url = request.Url;
        }
    }
```

Whenever the WebView begins loading a new page, and the page has finished loading. it will call [`OnPageFinished`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)).